# How to prevent cron jobs from being run during certain times in Debian? (a 'gaming' / 'performance mode')

Tags: debian, cron, performance, cpu, laptop

It looks like I have logcheck set up as a cron job and whenever it's run process `grep` by `logcheck` takes up around ¼ of my CPU.

Now I have certain times during which I need my full CPU capacity and have my system take up fewest resources as possible except for specific/processes (which I maybe could specify somehow).

Is it possible to set my Debian 9.1 with KDE machine into some sort of performance mode (or 'Gaming mode') that prevents processes not explicitly started by the user from taking up much system resources, lowers the load of background-processes and most importantly: delays cron jobs until that mode is stopped again?

Comment: A simple solution would be not to run logcheck in the cron job, but instead to write a custom script and run that in the cron job. In the script, first perform whatever checks you need and then run logcheck at the end of the script if those checks all pass.

Comment: Check the priority.  If it has been niced down to 19 it only runs when the cpu has nothing else to do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If “certain times” aren’t fixed, *i.e.* you want to specify manually when your system enters and leaves “performance mode”, you can simply stop and start `cron`:

```
sudo systemctl stop cron
```

will prevent any cron jobs from running, and

```
sudo systemctl start cron
```

will re-enable them.

You could also check out `anacron` instead of `cron`, it might be easier to tweak globally in a way which would fit your uses.

Answer (score 12):

I would consider two approaches

1. Leave the scheduling untouched but run all `cron` jobs under [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice), and possibly even [`ionice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice):

   ```
   0 * * * *    root    ionice -c3 nice /some/command and parameters
   ```
2. Disallow any `cron` jobs during certain times. Remember that any user who can create (or remove) the flag file can control this approach. That might work if you want to have a gaming mode that is set up *on demand*, by adding the `touch` and `rm` commands to your game's start-up script. (You might need to use `/tmp` rather than `/var/run`, but then it's trivially open to any user.)

   ```
   0 18 * * *      root    touch /var/run/no_cron
   0 19 * * *      root    rm -f /var/run/no_cron

   0 * * * *       root    test ! -f /var/run/no_cron && /some/command...
   ```

Once set up, neither approach requires root access. Moreover you can decide in advance which jobs should be subject to this control, and which must not.

Comment: Correct. Why bottleneck a process when there is plenty of CPU available? OS priorities kick in when there's a scarcity, not arbitrarily.

Comment: I don't believe the `-c3 -n7` combination makes sense, at least on Linux. The *idle* scheduling class has no priorities.

Comment: @gardenhead oops you're right. I use `-c2 -n7` myself but when I dropped the class to _idle_ for this answer I omitted to remove the priority.